# Configuring an external launcher for Eclipse over SSH with pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, raspberry-pi, pydev

Hoping that this is the right place to ask this:

I have my Eclipse-Python IDE with PyDev on my windows machine.

My codes/project files are on my Rasp-Pi (Remote machine)

I connect the Eclipse with "Remote System Explorer" Addon via SSH.I can work on the remote code and execute it over the SSH-Terminal (or Putty) so far it works good.

Now I fail at configuring a remote launcher for the project. I just want to run/debug project within Eclipse-IDE (i.e. just via shortcut-key F11) and the Remote machine (Rasp-Pi) executes the code and does stuff.

I dream about a configuration field like

```
(ssh pi@0.00.00.00 &) python %1
```

EDIT

I am able to run my script remotely via a command prompt. All I want to do is to run the scripts with the standard launcher of eclipse configuring it, see pics.
[image]
[image]